# Laravel response json useless array

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5.3

I'm working on an API with Laravel and I have a problem with my json response, for example I have ina function :

```
    $company = Company::select('name')
        ->inRandomOrder()
        ->limit(1)
        ->get();

    return response()->json([
        'company' => $company,
    ]);
```

With this I get when I call my function :

```
{
    "company": [
        {
            "name": "Company Number 1"
        }
    ]
}
```

Why I have an array after company ? `"company": [` Is there a way to return directly `$company` without an object before (named company in my example ?)

Thanks !

Comment: Try `first` method instead of `get`

Comment: Hum, good idea :p

Answer (score 6, accepted):

change your `->get()` to `->first()` so it returns the first model instead of a collection of models.

```
$company = Company::select('name')
    ->inRandomOrder()
    ->first();

return response()->json([
    'company' => $company,
]);
```

also `->limit(1)` is probably unnecessary as first already does this.

Answer (score 1):

`->get()` returns [Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-collections) while `first()` returns the first object or the collection.

Therefore, limit(1) is no longer required, and the default action of Laravel is to response as JSON.

As a result, you can simply

```
return [
  'company' => Company::select('name')->inRandomOrder()->first()
];
```